# Xcode Record UI test - How to remove XCTestCase auto generated code drop downs

Tags: ios, xcode

See the attached screen shot, when generating Xcode UI Test code using the record button, the generated code contains annoying drop downs that I cannot figure out how to remove.

[image]

[image]

Comment: These drop-downs are offering you a choice of ways to refer to these interface elements. That's good. What harm do they do you?

Comment: @matt They don't allow you to change the text, and they also contain extra cruft that i dont want in version control

Comment: In previous versions a double click on the bubble would make it go away. Not anymore... how annoying. I filed rdar://37978760

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any built-in function in Xcode to do this, so the best I can come up with is a regex that you can use to search and replace:

```
/\*@START_MENU_TOKEN@\*/|/\*\[.+\]@END_MENU_TOKEN@\*/
```

Interestingly, this works in the Xcode editor too, even if the actual texts `START_MENU_TOKEN` and so on are converted into dropdowns and as such invisible.

Answer (score 5):

When the popover is not displayed, then double-clicking on the code removes the menu tokens. It will now no longer appear in version control.

If the popover has appeared you need to select a value or otherwise dismiss the popover before the double-clicking works.

If there was a bug in earlier versions of Xcode, it is working at least in Xcode 10.3 (and possibly earlier versions)