# Xcode UI tests recorder generates long lines with multiple options

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

Are there any settings to reduce the amount of code generated?

This is what gets generated

```
windowsQuery/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.tabs["{ Test }"]/*[[".tabGroups.tabs[\"{ Test }\"]",".tabs[\"{ Test }\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/.click()
```

whereas everything i need is just

```
windowsQuery.tabs["{ Test }"].click()
```

I wouldn't care about that but Swiftlint is complaining. It shows ok in the editor but copy/pasting experience is horrible. It works ok but it's not needed.

Comment: Took me some time to find a duplicate... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361199/xcode-record-ui-test-how-to-remove-xctestcase-auto-generated-code-drop-downs However the solution there doesn't suit me - looks like a hack. It doesn't remove extra options.

Comment: Search didn't help me the first time. May be it will be easier to find this question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double tapping the optional code converts it into simple text. It's not intuitive but it works on xcode 10.2.1.